# Как скачать java

Tags: java

Сcылка на чтото новое или тип того для скачивания не открывается

Comment: https://www.java.com/ru/download/

Comment: Google java download

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Держи ссылку. http://g.zeos.in/?q=JDK%20download

Вообще сначала разберись, что такое JDK.

Comment: Всем спасибо, я уже 3 месяца, как работаю.